# Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateGt does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I have a set of validation rules in laravel. there are two date fields that one of them have to be greater than other. but when I use gt operator, an error apears:

```
$validation =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'description'   => 'required|string',
   'started_at'    => 'required|date',
   'finished_at'   => 'required|date|gt:started_at',
]);
```

error is: `Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validateGt does not exist.`

Comment: last version. 5.6 @prd

Comment: *'required|date|gt:started_at'*, **'gt:started_at'** is wrong, **gt** rule does not exist in laravel, you can use *'required|date|after:started_at'*,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**gt:started_at** is wrong  **gt** rule does not exist in laravel use **after**

```
$validation =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'description'   => 'required|string',
   'started_at'    => 'required|date',
   'finished_at'   => 'required|date|after:started_at',
]);
```

Comment: @reza are you try my answer??